# What's the difference between [[False] * 26] * 26] and [[False] * 26 for _ in range(0, 26)]?

Tags: python, list

What's the difference between `[[False] * 26] * 26]` and `[[False] * 26 for _ in range(0, 26)]` in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about aliasing.  It becomes apparent when you modify the inner list.

```
>>> a = [[False] * 26] * 26
>>> a[0][0] = True
>>> a[1][0]
True
>>> b = [[False] * 26 for _ in range(0, 26)]
>>> b[0][0] = True
>>> b[1][0]
False
```